# How to check if field A OR field B is empty?

Tags: php

I have a drop down list that is populated from the MySQL server but I also have a text box for the user to add a vendor if it isn't already listed. I need a way to say that vendor OR new vendor is required.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, check if both fields are empty. If so send them back to the page with an error message.

Comment: If I ask for both fields then they won't be able to complete the form because they only need to put data in one of the fields...

Comment: check `$_POST['vendor_field'] === "" || $_POST['new_vendor_field'] === ""`

Comment: Honestly you should have an option in your dropdown labelled "Create New...", and when it is selected then the "new vendor" form fields appear. Server-side, check if the selected vendor is the "create new" option, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Use [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on your inputs too.

Comment: how do create the option to create new in the drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  put your request processing code in an if block. I am considering that the form is using POST method. This should work fine for you.

```
<?
    if($_POST['vendor_from_list'] != "" || $_POST['vendor_from_txtbox'] != ""){
        //Your data processing code, here.
    }else{
        echo "vendor OR new vendor is required.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Short tags might not be enabled so suggesting the OP to use them is a bad idea.

Comment: What if I submit a space? How would the validation prevent that?

Comment: '*vendor OR new vendor is required.*' - No, based on your logic, it is AND.